Blender 4 - in Toggle Quad View - how to maximise Top, Front, Left etc?
I have for convenience the Industry Standard Keymap and not the Blender native Keymap.
For Quick Access, I have assigned a Shortcut to Toggle Quad View.
In Quad View, how can I maximise let's say the Top View etc?
Is there a way to assign or modify a particular Shortcut?
— I haven't found any useful info unless I would use Blender native Keymap, which I am unwilling to adapt. —
